# What is the best way to create a dynamic form with many sections

Tags: usability, design, dynamic-ui

I have a scenario where a client wants a full wizard with steps to create a full report with a large dynamic form. It is dynamic in the sense not all sections and fields are required but its possible all can be used.

The wizard will flow like this.

Screen 1. Basic Client information with uploading a profile photo

Screen 2A. A dynamic form to build the report. This form has sections. Each section has multiple tabs. Each tab holds a table or form fields.
Screen 2A(addition). The client wants to be able to load data from a previous form  to save time.

Screen 3. Will show a preview of the report.
Screen 4. Shows if the report was saved and a report number

I have attached a photo of the current layout as I have no idea how to show so many sections and fields in a user friendly format.

Comment: Add more steps. Create logic clusters if possible to reduce the number of steps. It's easier to follow steps than to read extensive content in accordions
P.S.: Prioritize accessibility. The current format is nearly unreadable.

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 2):

From what I've seen, especially with hiring sites, is that they split their forms into individual pages and then show you all your inputs at the end, on a "Review" page.

This is similar to what [TypedForms](https://www.typeform.com/templates/t/simple-registration/) does by splitting up your form into smaller chunks so that they are more easily digestible by the user.